# Where precisely was Russian town of Osometz (1912)?

Tags: 20th-century, russia, historical-gazetteer

In 1912 was there a town or city called Osometz in russia?
records show my grandmother came from Osometz russia in 1912.

Example from the passenger list of the Campania, arriving in New York NY from Liverpool England on 3 Mar 1912 (indexed as Osometz at both EllisIsland and Ancestry):

[image: Details from 1912 Campania passenger list]

Comment: Can you show us what you mean by "records"?

Comment: Is the 'm' in Osometz actually a 'w'?

Comment: Records, plural?  What records do you have? Can you snip out the place name and show us the handwriting?

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  There is an **edit** button beneath your question that you can use to add the extra details that people are requesting here via comments.

Comment: If your grandmother is Xenia (on the passenger list page imaged above), then you have a golden opportunity: she was traveling with 5 others from the same location, including a brother & his wife. If you haven't already done so, researching their records may help localize 'Osometz.' This is an important research tactic, that aids indirectly when direct evidence is hard to find.

Comment: Thanks for including the scan but I'd like to see the full page so we see more of the handwriting. I am sceptical that the first letter is an O. It might be a C. We can read Grabowo which is quite clearly Polish but sadly Wikipedia lists 27 of them in Poland.

Comment: @user3310902 I was going to include the full image urls with the excerpt, however both ellisisland and ancestry require sign-ins and have complex urls for the images. If you are registered at EllisIsland or have a U.S. ancestry subscription, the images are easy enough to search and access - note that I specified both sites have the place indexed as Osometz. Also, the OP did not include the actual details or name, so I didn't want to add further references to a possibly erroneous match.

Answer (score 4):

It could be Osowetz from North-Eastern Poland, Russian Empire in 1912 -http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osowiec-Twierdza.

Comment: Excellent find, vladich. There are two near each other - Osowiec and Osowiec-Twierdra. I also see on Google Maps that there is a Grabowo about 30 miles/ 55 km to the west of these two places. Although Wikipedia mentions 12 Osowiecs in Poland (though this can be reduced because some were in Germany in 1912). How do we know this is the right one? - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osowiec

Comment: You're right, it could be any of those villages located in Russian Empire by 1912 (some of them were in Germany as you said or probably in Austria-Hungary). Most of them were smaller than Osowiec-Twierdza though. We need more info to figure out what is the most probable location.

Answer (score 0):

[Having seen the scan, I am withdrawing this] First shot in the dark without seeing it written in a record is Bolshoi Samovets near Gryazi, south of Moscow towards Ukraine. But really needs corroboration.

First to clarify there are two villages of the same name, in the same region. I looked at the 1910 gazetteer for the Marx map, figured Oso was unlikely so went for alternatives. Apparently the locals drop the Bolshoi. Just say it quickly. I'm really not wedded to this. OP needs to provide more info to work from.

Comment: Could you clarify how you got from Osometz to Bolshoi Samovets please?

Comment: First to clarify there are two villages of the same name, in the same region. I looked at the 1910 gazetteer for the Marx map, figured Oso was unlikely so went for alternatives. Apparently the locals drop the Bolshoi. Just say it quickly. I'm really not wedded to this. OP needs to provide more info to work from.